# SSL Error when using local cert to verify

Tags: python

Error Message Data

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 313, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3510)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 315, in ssl_wrap_socket
    raise SSLError(e)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3510)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='controlpanel.peopleadmin.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sessions/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3510)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cody.jones/PycharmProjects/loginhandler/test.py", line 48, in <module>
    response = ses.post(url, values, verify='cert.cer')
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cody.jones\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='controlpanel.peopleadmin.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sessions/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3510)'),))
```

My code

```
values = {'system_user[username]' : username,
          'system_user[password]' : password,
          'authenticity_token' : token }

#begin session
ses = requests.Session()
response = ses.post(url, values, verify='cert.cer')
```

I have  copied the SSL cert by downloading the data with openSSL.  However I'm still getting a ton of errors from this and I don't see what I could be doing wrong.  I'm trying to resolve the issues with SSL because when I connect with my script over my VPN (instead of being in the actual office) it has an issue with its SSL verification.  I need this software to work regardless of whether or not you're over a VPN since I'm usually on a VPN.

Comment: when you are not using VPN does it work fine?

Comment: Not this code, but the code I was using before this did but I was trying to specify the  certs that I downloaded to see if it was having an issue pulling it because of the VPN

Comment: This is a client side certificate to verify yourself against the server, right? If that is the case I think you may need to provide the [`cert`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates) option instead

Comment: I think its a server certificate, I just pulled the data from openssl with s_client.

Comment: You need a **Client side** Cert, ask the admin of the server to get one.